# Acrobat: How can I insert simple text using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, text, acrobat

I want to add a simple text box and not a form field into a PDF. The code

```
var f = this.addField("fieldname", "text", Page_num,[x1,y1,x2,y2]);
```

obviously creates a form field which contaminates my PDF so that it's a form.

Thanks in advance!
Rudi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not add text to the base of a document using (Acrobat) JavaScript (unless you add a field or an annotation and then flatten the page).

If you think of a text box as an annotation, you would use addAnnot(). For syntax and options of the annotation object see the Acrobat JavaScript documentation, which is part of the Acrobat SDK, downloadable from the Adobe website.

BTW, I do resent the term "contaminate"…